# Trouble upgrading to rails 2.3.15 with rack 1.1.3

Tags: rack

I'm getting the following error when trying to fire up script/console for my rails 2.3.15 app, after upgrading from rails 2.3.5. Does this mean the issue is with bundler 1.2.1 is not compatible with rack 1.1.3? Any help would be appreciated immensely.

usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:157:in `gem': can't activate rack (~> 1.0.1), already activated rack-1.1.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller.rb:34
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in`new_constants_in'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:2
    from script/server:3:in`require'
    from script/server:3

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem solved by the following steps:

1. Deleted the directory `$PROJECT_ROOT/vendor/rails`
2. Modified `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` in `config/environment.rb`

Comment: Did you just modify to this?

RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.15' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

Comment: I ended up having to use a patch since I could not upgrade easily to a new version of rails. Get the patches here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ

Answer (score -1):

we used this process to upgrade Rails to 3.2.11 on our Heroku apps (as reported [here](http://chris-augeri.com/blog/2013/01/08/late-night-just-might-work-guide-to-upgrade-ruby-on-rails-server-during-great-rails-vulnerability-of-2013/))

```
stop – your Ruby on Rails (RoR) server
edit  – appropriate line in gem file to read [one of]:
    gem ‘rails’, ’3.2.11′
    gem ‘rails’, ’3.1.10′
    gem ‘rails’, ’3.0.19′
    gem ‘rails’, ’2.3.15′

run – gem update
run – bundle update
run - bundle install

test – rspec # or test-driven dev’t framework of choice
launch – rails s
test – # interact with Rails server & explore if all is well

run – git add .
run – git commit -a -m “upgrade Rails server to ver. [x.y.z]“
run - git push # to github or rcs of choice
run - git push heroku # or to deployment server of choice
```

Comment: Thanks, Aghilmort. But those are the exact steps that I followed except the server cannot boot in the end and gives the errors that I pasted to start this thread.